# Aplicar regex a .csv

Tags: linux, regex, ubuntu, sed

estoy haciendo un script de sed.

Estoy trabjando con el siguiente dataset:

```
1;   2;   3; 4;     5;      6;    7; 8; 9;       10;    11;  12
431; Yes; 1; Ramon; male;   28.0; 0; 0; 110564;  26.55; C52; S
664; No;  3; Jorge; male;   36.0; 0; 0; 349210;  7.4958;   ; S
347; Yes; 2; Sergi; female; 40.0; 0; 0; 31418;   13.0;     ;
```

Como podéis ver, la columna `10` tiene valores con más de dos decimales o bien con menos de dos. Lo que quiero, es que me corrija el valor y siempre tenga dos decimales. En ese sentido, si el valor de la columna `10` es 13.0 la corrección será 13.00. Por otro lado, si el valor es 7.4958, truncara el valor y será 7.49. He hecho lo siguiente:

```
#!/bin/sed -f
s/\([0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\)[0-9]*/\1/g
s/\([0-9]\.[0-9]\)\>/\10/g
```

Sin embargo, cuado ejecuto el script:

```
./fix_decimales.sed archivo.csv
```

Me cambia todos los valores de las columnas que cumplan con el patrón. Cómo puedo indicar-le que sólo compute para la columna `10`?

La salida deberia ser algo como:

```
1;   2;   3; 4;     5;      6;    7; 8; 9;       10;    11;  12
431; Yes; 1; Ramon; male;   28.0; 0; 0; 110564;  26.55; C52; S
664; No;  3; Jorge; male;   36.0; 0; 0; 349210;  7.49;     ; S
347; Yes; 2; Sergi; female; 40.0; 0; 0; 31418;   13.00;    ;
```

Comment: Por otra parte, ¿por qué en Sed? En otras preguntas has usado Awk, que parece mucho mejor herramienta para hacer redondeos.

Comment: Lo hago en sed porqué se trata de un trabajo y se me pide esto explicitamente. He modificado el enunciado.

Comment: Tela... hacerlo con Sed. Como pista, ten en cuenta que muchos campos cumplen la condición que le das. Por tanto, también debes coger la parte de los 9 primeros campos e imprimirla de nuevo. `sed -r 's/^(([^;]*;){9})/\1 ---/' fichero` te los imprime, por ejemplo.

Comment: Este es el problema que estoy teniendo. Te refieres a poner esta línea delante de mi regex?

Comment: Sí. No está depurado el ejemplo, pero básicamente debes capturar los primeros 9 campos para luego actuar sobre el que te interesa que es el 10.º.